# Put the one box down exactly to the other

Tags: html

In html I have this form:

```
<form action="index.php" method="GET">
        Name <input type="text" name="FirstName" size="10" /><br />
        <br />
        Surname: <input type="text" name="LastName" size="10" /><br />
        <br />
</form>
```

It is a for with the first and last name. Is it possible to make the one box to be exactly down to the other. Because the first box is closer to name because it has less letters than the surname and respectively it takes the space?

Answer (score 0):

Without using `CSS` simplest way to do this, is using `Table` of HTML.

Consider this Snippet:

```html
<form action="index.php" method="GET">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="FirstName" size="10" />
            <br />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Surname:</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="LastName" size="10" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: structure and style should be kept seperate and html tables are not a layout option

Comment: OP has not mentioned `CSS` tag in question. So i provided `HTML` solution @Billy

Comment: Just because there's no CSS tag does not mean " Please provide me with an answer that flies in the face of current standards, Ignoring anything that is specifically for presentation, And give me something that is semantically incorrect so that I can learn wrong from the very start and maybe one day I will try and learn CSS"

Answer (score 0):

here's one way you could do it.

```css
input{position:absolute;left:80px;}
```

```html
<form action="index.php" method="GET">
        <label>Name</label> <input type="text" name="FirstName" size="10" />
       
  <br><br>
        <label>Surname:</label> <input type="text" name="LastName" size="10" />
        
</form>
```

Comment: Giving position absolution is bad practice, when you'll be checking in different devices

Comment: Not perfect but not bad practice, There's lots of uses for position absolute. lists for menus use it alot. However using HTML Tables for  layout is bad practice , the link is [http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-table-element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-table-element). Quote below is from this link but too long to put on one comment.

Comment: Tables should not be used as layout aids. Historically, many Web authors have tables in HTML as a way to control their page layout making it difficult to extract tabular data from such documents. In particular, users of accessibility tools, like screen readers, are likely to find it very difficult to navigate pages with tables used for layout.

Comment: second part of quote does say this "If a table is to be used for layout it must be marked with the attribute role="presentation" for a user agent to properly represent the table to an assistive technology and to properly convey the intent of the author to tools that wish to extract tabular data from the document." and I cannot see `role="presentation"` anywhere in your code.....and of course the note "There are a variety of alternatives to using HTML tables for layout, primarily using CSS positioning and the CSS table model." which Oriol's answer uses.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should improve your HTML. `<br />` are ugly and you should associate the text with the `input`s using `label`s:

```html
<form action="index.php" method="GET">
  <label>
    Name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" size="10" />
  </label>
  <label>
    Surname: <input type="text" name="LastName" size="10" />
  </label>
</form>
```

Now, you can try displaying the `form` as a table:

```css
form {
  display: table;
}
label{
  display: table-row;
}
```

```css
form {
  display: table;
}
label{
  display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<form action="index.php" method="GET">
  <label>
    Name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" size="10" />
  </label>
  <label>
    Surname: <input type="text" name="LastName" size="10" />
  </label>
</form>
```

And now, to align the `input`s,

- You can align the content to the right:

  ```css
  label {
    text-align: right;
  }
  ```

  ```css
  form {
    display: table;
  }
  label{
    display: table-row;
    text-align: right;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <form action="index.php" method="GET">
    <label>
      Name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" size="10" />
    </label>
    <label>
      Surname: <input type="text" name="LastName" size="10" />
    </label>
  </form>
  ```
- Or, if you want the text aligned to the left, you can float the `input`s to the right:

  ```css
  input {
    float: right;
  }
  ```

  ```css
  form {
    display: table;
  }
  label{
    display: table-row;
  }
  input {
    float: right;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <form action="index.php" method="GET">
    <label>
      Name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" size="10" />
    </label>
    <label>
      Surname: <input type="text" name="LastName" size="10" />
    </label>
  </form>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<form action="index.php" method="GET">
       <label>Name:</label><input type="text" name="FirstName" size="10" /><br />
        <br />
        <label>Surname:</label> <input type="text" name="LastName" size="10" /><br />
        <br />
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```
label{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: right;
}
input {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/4ncwzLpx/